# How to put data into multi dimensional array in js inside the loop

Tags: javascript, php, json, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

How can we put data into multi dimensional array or json within a loop. 
I know that it's possible to store multi dimensional data at one time, but I want it inside the loop as I have described in the code.

```
var sub_cat_checked_val = [];    
sub_cat_checked.each(function (index) {
    var sub_cat_id = jQuery(this).attr('name').replace('subcategory_id_', '').replace('[]', '');
    sub_cat_checked_val['key_one']['key_two']='value';
    sub_cat_checked_val[sub_cat_id][index] = index:jQuery(this).val();
});
```

As it's possible in php like `$var_name['key1']['key2']['keyn']='value';`

Comment: ?..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sub_cat_checked_val[sub_cat_id] needs to be defined as an array, so add the lines:

```
if (!sub_cat_checked_val[sub_cat_id]) {
    sub_cat_checked_val[sub_cat_id] = [];
}
```

to define the value as an array if it does not exist.

Comment: Please remember to format code as code (using either backticks or 4-space/tab indentation)

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
<script>
var k = {};
k.a = {};
k.a.b = {};
k.a.b.c = {};
k.a.b.c.d = 5;
console.log(k);
</script>
```

Comment: I want value of the variable should be key like if a=2, then when using k.a='Value' it should return {k:{2:Value}}

Comment: With numerical ones it won't work, but you can always add an underscore as a prefix, so for example: k._2._14._21 = 35;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with all of you guys help with some of modifications.

Here is what I did:

```
        sub_cat_checked.each(function (index) {
            console.log(index_val);
            var sub_cat_id = jQuery(this).attr('name').replace('subcategory_id_', '').replace('[]', '');
            console.log(sub_cat_id);
            if (sub_cat_checked_val[sub_cat_id] == undefined) {
                sub_cat_checked_val[sub_cat_id] = [];
            }

            sub_cat_checked_val[sub_cat_id][index] = jQuery(this).val();
        });
```

Thanks a lot to all of you.